# Style depending on the first class only?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where I need to style my elements depending on their first class (only). My titles are auto-generated with many tags on them (depending on categories) however I want to use the first category tag to style my elements. Here is an example:

```
<div class="tag-text tag-design tag-architecture">TITLE HERE</div>
```

...and a CSS codebit:

```
.tag-architecture {
  background-color: purple;
}
.tag-text {
  background-color: black;
}
.tag-design {
  background-color: green;
}
```

As you can guess, if the html element has 3 of the tags at the same time, it's styled depending on the last part of the CSS, in this case `.tag-design`.

Is it possible to style the element depeinding on the first class (in this case `.tag-text`) only - so that the background stays black for this specific situation?

Comment: Put `.tag-text` last?

Comment: Would they always be in a similar order? If you added `!important` to the css class it will take a priority over the others. It would look like so: `background-color: black!important;`

Comment: no they're always in different order, the tags are dynamically generated -

Comment: I guess reordering the css won't help in this case since you could also have `tag-architecture tag-design tag-text`? You probably need to use javascript to get what you're asking for.

Comment: Even if you do get this working, it's fragile. If any other page functionality adds classes or changes class order it breaks. I'd take a completely different approach. For example, whatever auto-generates your classes should also remove other competing classes.

Comment: @isherwood I'm looking for a solid solution, yes. Any alternative ideas in mind?

Comment: Another option might be to add your classes in reverse order, and also add additional nested wrapper elements so that the innermost element (div) has the primary class. CSS specificity will get the job done, then. The drawback is added structural complexity, especially if you have more than a few possible classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with CSS3 Substring Matching Attribute Selectors

```
[class^="tag-architecture"] {
  background-color: purple;
}

[class^="tag-text"] {
  background-color: black;
}

[class^="tag-design"] {
  background-color: green;
}
```

CSS3 Substring Matching Attribute Selectors are as follows:

```
[att^=val] – the "begins with" selector
[att$=val] – the "ends with" selector
[att*=val] – the "contains" selector
```

Comment: So how it's working actually? [class^= is everywhere so why black background is first

Comment: Wow, it's working. As [class^="tag-design"] (with quotes) (for correction). This is really a powerful method -

Comment: It should be noted that this will not override any styles imposed by the other classes....for that you would need to further qualify the selctor with `not` statements

Comment: @Zettam, Yes If value have any special characters, It should be enclosed in quotes. Now corrected the answer.

Comment: A small gotcha you may need to look out for is if tags have similar names (i.e. `tag-text` vs `tag-textarea`). Just make sure the longer name is declared after the shorter name to override the earlier declaration.